# Убрать _id из запроса данных mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Есть бд в которой находятся 3 значения:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ab781e5ae47fccd161ef614"), "site" : 
"https://test.ru/" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ab781f8ae47fccd161ef615"), "site" : 
"https://test2.ru/" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ab78206ae47fccd161ef616"), "site" : 
"https://test3.ru/" }
```

Пытаюсь извлечь эти данные без ObjectId:

```
            var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
            var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
            var arrSites =[];


            MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //Return only the "name" field in the result:
                var dbo = db.db("nameSites");
                dbo.collection("newsSites").find({}, { _id: 0, site: 1 }).toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
                        arrSites[i]=result[i];
                    }
                    console.log(arrSites);
                    db.close();
                });

            });
```

Но в результате получаю полные данные, где _id также отображается, как это исправить?

Comment: какую версию MongoDB используете? Там есть отличия

Comment: Использую 
db version v3.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по коду, Вы используете, скорее всего модуль MongoDB версии 3.0. Для него изменился синктасис подобного запроса. Вторым параметром идет объект, в котором могут быть несколько опций. В Вашем случае, опция называется `projection`. Поэтому так и указываете:

```
var options = {
    projection: {
        _id: 0, 
        site: 1
    }
}

dbo.collection("newsSites").find({}, options).toArray.....
```

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то не мог разобраться!

Comment: Неделю назад, я с той же проблемой мучался).