# Как работать с циклами в node.js? (синхронно/асинхронно)

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, mongodb, mongoose

Есть обработчик POST запросов на авторизацию, если ему поступает запрос, то он берет пришедший username ищет в базе данных mongoose, если находит, сверяет password и теперь вопрос:

Нужно из полученного из базы значения объекта user, в котором много полей (**username, userid, password, email итд**) получить только определенные, допустим **username** и **userid** можно ли это сделать через обычный цикл **for in** это же синхронное действие (с расчетом на большую нагруженность)

```
User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
        if (user.checkPassword(password)) {
            // Ok auth
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему не вытащить из БД,  только те поля, которые надо? Зачем доставать Все, а потом еще и циклом выбирать?

Comment: А разве можно сделать выборку в mongoose/mongodb? И если да, то как?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804369/Убрать-id-из-запроса-данных-mongodb/804379#804379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

метод `findOne` вторым параметром позволяет задать поля, которые нужно вернуть:

```
User.findOne(
  {username: username},
  {"username": true, "userid": true},
  function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
      if (user.checkPassword(password)) {
          // Ok auth
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let obj = {
 name: 'qwa',
 foo(_f) {
  _f.call(this)
 }
}
let ass = () => Promise.resolve('qwa')
obj.foo(async function () {
 // console.log(this);
 console.log(
  await ass()
 );//qwa
})
obj.foo(function () {
 // console.log(this);
 console.log(
  ass()
 );//Promise {<resolved>: "qwa"}
})
```

Comment: А можно поподробнее что делает этот код?

Comment: @Artem,  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function - async/await async - говорит что функция асинхронна await говорит подождать результат `let res = await someF()`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как тут происходит выборка из всех пришедших полей определенных(нужных) полей

Comment: эт уже другой вопрос, к гуру mongoose, приведённый мной пример показывает, как можно получить данные из асинхронной функции. глядя на заголовок, мне показалось что проблема с этим. (Как работать в node.js синхронно/асинхронно)